# What is the point of patching patchfiles?

Tags: git, version-control

I work with a software vendor who generally distributes code as `git am`-like patches in `.patch` files, which works reasonably well.

Occasionally, instead of providing a commit as a patch file, which patches a source file (i.e. `.c`), they tend to patch up one of the older patch files.

In case it's not clear what I'm describing, the diff often looks like this:

```
second.patch:

diff --git a/first.patch b/first.patch
index 4a2f020..2ea53fe 100644
--- a/first.patch  #notice this isn't a source file, but rather a older patch provided
+++ b/second.patch
 <whatever>
```

I'd assume there should be a very good reason, since they do it very rarely, and it's very annoying.

To me, I see a huge downside of having to maintain older `.patch` files to apply the new one, which should be completely unnecessary.

Is there a  reason why one would do this?

Comment: It seems their patches are also managed by a git repo. So the old patch plus the patch patch can make the new patch. But why not ask the vendor why they do this?

Comment: Heh, turns out it's their way of doing `git commit --amend` so that they don't actually touch the older patch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's their way of doing `git commit --amend` so that they don't actually modify the older patch files